# Percorrer todo o json devolvendo os valores finais(Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Meu objetivo é visualizar os dados dos 'files'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hey João, uma pequena dica que pode te ajudar aqui no site: Sempre que for fazer perguntas poste em formato de texto, contamos com umas ferramentas de edição bem bacanas. Isso nos ajuda a te ajudar, pois fica mais fácil copiarmos seu código para lhe ajudar. Use imagens para demonstrar layouts e coisas afins.

Answer (score 0):

O seu JSON está um pouco complicado porque o objeto *Files* não é uma lista comum.

Uma possível solução é a seguinte:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> json = {
    "qtdDocs": 2,
    "tokenUser": "asdkoqwn123",
    "files": {
      "0": {"name": "file1"},
      "1": {"name": "file2"}
    }
  };

  // Métodos auxiliares
  Map<String, dynamic> getFile(int index) {
    // Pega o objeto de arquivos
    final Map<String, dynamic> files = json["files"];
    // Lista as chaves de cada arquivo
    final List<String> chaves = files.keys.toList();
    // Pega o nome do arquivo que está no index informado
    final fileKey = chaves[index];

    // Pega o objeto do arquivo pelo nome e retorna o mesmo
    return files[fileKey];
  }

  void extrairArquivos() {
    // Loop para percorrer os arquivos
    for (var i = 0; i < json["qtdDocs"]; i++) {
      final file = getFile(i);

      // Faz o que precisa aqui
      print(file);
    }
  }

  // Executa a extração dos arquivos
  extrairArquivos();
}
```

*O JSON do meu exemplo está bem parecido com o seu, apenas simplifiquei para o exemplo.*

**Explicação**

Criei um for-loop que vai até a posição *qtdDocs*. Assim, vamos percorrendo os objetos dentro do "Files" pelos indexes.

> Obs.: Você pode testar em [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id).